# Steps to install php mysql on centos 6.8

Tags: centos-6, php5, mysql5

I have a server with centos 6.8
I am trying to install

1. php 5.5.
2. mysql 5.5
3. php-mbstring

But it shows error message as: 
Error: php55w-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.3-48.el6_8.x86_64

Please tell me step by step guide to install.

Comment: Chick this link for installing [php-mbstring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278561/how-to-install-php-mbstring-on-centos-6-2)

Answer (score 1):

to remove the previous install

`yum remove php-common-5.3.3-48.el6_8.x86_64`

this was suggested on another forum:

`rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm`

you can install php5.5 using

`yum install php55w php55w-opcache`

or upgrade your existing installation using

`yum install yum-plugin-replace`

`yum replace php-common --replace-with=php55w-common`

package name for mbstring is 
`php55w-mbstring`

the package name for mysql is 
`php55w-mssql`

information for centos was aquired from

https://webtatic.com/packages/php55/

---

information for linux debian/ubuntu based below

---

for if you do not have it, you can install the ondrej PPA

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
```

or the general php ppa

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

if this gives an error for UTF 8 localization you can use

```
LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
```

or

```
LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

then uninstall the previous php installation

```
sudo apt purge php-common-5.3.3-48.el6_8.x86_64
```

and update your ppa lists with

```
sudo apt update
```

right after
if this all went correctly you should be able to use

```
sudo apt-get install php(version of choice) mysql(version of choice) php-mbstring
```

Comment: sorry, i came to realize that centos doesn't use apt ill be looking for another answer! ill update this once i found the correct answer

Comment: you're welcome, just let me know if it worked or not :)